# I'm trying to subset from multiple obs in scanpy

Tags: python, subset, bioinformatics, scanpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42U6X.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P85Ho.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCUkl.png)

Hello.
I am a beginner who is studying scanpy.
I'm trying to subset from multiple obs in scanpy.

I can subset clusters in one obs.
However, I want to subset clusters of 'pEMT' and 'Oxphos' among 'obs' at the same time as one adata.

Is there a way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shows that 'pEMT' and 'Oxphos' are columns in the obs dataframe.

If you are subsetting the adata object based on pMET as `adata[adata.obs['pMET']==somevalue]` and subsetting based on Oxphos as `adata[adata.obs['Oxphos']==somevalue]` you can "and" the conditions as this to subset based on the both of the columns:

`adata[(adata.obs['pMET']==somevalue) & (adata.obs['Oxphos']==somevalue)]`

Note that `adata.obs['somecolumn']==somevalue` returns a Series object of booleans. You can do element-wise boolean arithemtic on these, for example you can use & (and), | (or), ~ (not) operators.